# Is there a way to create a python foreground service on android?

Tags: python, java, android

I am developing an AI Voice assistant using python. I made an app using kivy to connect with my ai using python sockets. I can control my mobile phone using the AI. But, when the application goes to sleep or closed. My app client is not listening for any commands from AI. Is there a way to create a foreground service and add my listener to it.

**Note:** The listener will get commands from AI Server and execute it. Eg: opening other applications.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using [Wake Lock](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock), you can read the official documentation here. I assume that you are using `buildozer` to create the `APK`, so for this in order to work, you will need to give your app a permission called `WAKE_LOCK`. It should at be around line 55 (im not sure) in the buildozer file:

```
# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, WAKE_LOCK
```

Comment: If I switch to another app will my app will be active. I don't want it to freeze. I want to create it like a background process.